# Does the Thomas-Fermi screening length formula only apply to metals?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, crystals, electronic-band-theory, nanoscience

**Does the Thomas-Fermi screening length formula only apply to metals?**

In my notes, the Thomas-Fermi screening length is:

$\lambda_{TF}^2 = \left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)^{1/3} \frac{\epsilon(0) a_0}{4n^{1/3} m^*} \tag{1}$

where $\lambda_{TF}$ indicates the screening-length, and $a_0$ is the Bohr radius ($5.29\times10^{−11}$ m), on the electron effective mass, $m^∗$, and $\epsilon(0)$  represents the dielectric constant of the material.

In my lecturer's notes, this screening length is only measured on metals. For me, it makes sense that this could be applied to other materials that are not metals, because I think that all variables are existing in other types of material, hence a value can be obtained for these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non metals are insulators and so cannot completely screen charge.  In terms of your formula, the density of free free-charges  $n$ is zero for non metals, and so $\lambda_{TF}=\infty$.

Comment: I know this is probably a very basic question, but no matter how much I read it, I can't understand, out of context, what the meaning of screening out a perturbation and screening charge. 
Most articles I have read, like Modern Techniques of Surface Sciences 3rd ed. by D. Phil Woodruff, simply mention screening without explaining it.

Comment: It means that any charge is surrounded by an equal and opposite charge  so that charges further apart than $\lambda$ feel no force due to each other.

Answer (score 1):

No, it applies whenever there are free charges. So, it applies to semiconductors too (especially doped ones) or even insulators if you can heat them up enough without melting them...

EDIT: by way of example, here is a classic paper that applies Thomas-Fermi screening to semiconductor heterostructures: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.41.7929 The formulas in that paper are different than the one you gave because the paper considers a 2D system rather than a 3D one. However, the principle is the same.